# How to play transferred DLC on different Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2, drm

Recently, my trusty 360 S miraculously RROD'ed on me. I sent it in for repair at my local game store, and they repaired by swapping out the thermal paste on the CPU/GPU Chip combination. The console works fine now, but I am cutting my loses short before I lost anymore valuable data to the RROD.

I moved my precious Black Ops 2 DLC to a USB and transferred that content from the USB to a new 360 E Console I got very recently. I downloaded my profile and went offline to play the DLCs, but when I go to Zombies or Multiplayer, the DLCs don't show up. I'm playing on the profile that bought them online, so I don't see why I shouldn't be able to play them.

How can I play my DLCs again on my new Xbox? I don't exactly want to redownload all the DLCs again to the new console, so a quick fire solution would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to move my DLC for Black Ops 2 to my 360 E. To move the DLC, I moved the DLC onto a USB on my old 360 and plugged in the USB into the 360 E. From there, I transferred the DLC to the E's local HDD.

After transferring said content, I logged into my Xbox Live Account to sync the DLCs to my new console, which did take some time to do (about an hour). Once synced, the DLCs now show up even in offline mode, allowing me to play regardless of me being online or offline.

From my experience, you only need to log in once into your Xbox Live Account to sync the DLCs to a new console.